# Iterating through values (floats) in a container dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, key-value-store

How do I iterate through values of a dictionary that are floats?

I have a dictionary whose multiple values are filenames that I want to rename according to the keys.

```
for k,v in dictionary.iteritems():
print(k,v)
```

this gives me this output:

Keys.........,             Values

(20026308, u'1224, 1225')

...

Now I want to say for each value, check if a file exists with that name the directory.

photodir = "C:\Desktop\phototest"
photosindir = glob.glob("C:\Desktop\phototest*.jpg")

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), since it is hard to tell exactly what problem you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import os
photodir = "C:\Desktop\phototest"
dict = {20026308 : u'1224, 1225'}
for k,v in dict.items():
    print(k,v)
    for photo_id in v.split():
        path_to_check = "C:\Desktop\phototest%s.jpg"%photo_id
        photo_exist = os.path.isfile(path_to_check)
        print(path_to_check, "exists : ", photo_exist)
```

gives :

```
20026308 1224, 1225
C:\Desktop\phototest1224,.jpg exists :  False
C:\Desktop\phototest1225.jpg exists :  False
```